# Splice gives blank screen on startup

Tags: 12.10, games, radeon, fglrx

I just installed splice from the humble bundle, and I get a blank screen on startup.  I can hear the audio, and if I move my mouse around, I can hear the menu items or something changing.

I have an amd radeon HD5800 series.  I'm using the fglrx-updates driver on 12.10, fully updated.

Any ideas of things to try?  Full screen or windowed, I get a blank window.  Also, other GL games are running just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to follow up here -- I installed appropriate amd beta drivers and now it starts.  These ones work, I cannot confirm that the latest ones do at the time of this writing (I had trouble with another game with the latest beta drivers).  I know with the Steam beta out now, there are a lot of changes in drivers coming along.

amd64:

http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.11-beta-x86.x86_64.zip